# Launch console with ant exec, using realine to wait is not working

Tags: c#, input, ant, console, readline

I've a selfHost webapi console, and this console must run while executing integration tests.

In a normal way, the console ends with a "Hit ENTER to exit... ".
Here I can't press enter, so my idea was to kill process at the end.

But When I launch my console with ant I've :

```
"Launch ConsoleHost"
"Hit ENTER to exit... "
"Console ending ... "
```

I know that input is redirected.

So how is it possible to solve my problem ?

- Change Console.ReadLine() in something else ?
- call ant exec in another way (with input setted... to what) ?

I've try exec spawn, parallel process, ant-contrib forget/wait

Please help :)

Console code is very simple :

```
static void Main()
{
  var host = new Host();

  host.Start();
  Console.ReadLine();
  host.Stop();

  Console.Out.WriteLine("Console ending ...");
}
```

Comment: What about extending your code with timeout parameter and Environment.exit(0) so it would exit with RC=0 when running in ant ?

Comment: I can't put a timout in my console : Outside Automation tests environnent, this console must run for days.... Maybe, if no param, no timeout. But then how to escape safely...

Comment: So make Environment.exit(0) dependant on that timeout parameter. Make timeout default = 0 and only exit if timeout > 0. Thus it may run with (hit Enter for exit) and without interaction (exit with f.e. RC 0 or other RC if timeout expired).

Comment: I've implemented this solution and it works. 
My only problem is that I don't like writing code only to fix a test problem..... But anyway, for the moment, it's the only way :) Thanks